# send data via get url

Tags: php

I have a problem I can not solve, I'm getting crazy. I have this link to pass data to a remote database using the get method.

this is the link

```
$res = get_data('http://www.campionandoalivorno.it/iwebkit/set_register.asp?' . 'user=' . urlencode($user) . '&pwd=' . urlencode($pwd) . '&email=' . urlencode($email) . '&recapito=' . urlencode($recapito)  . '&fanta=' . urlencode($fanta) . '&cognome=' . urlencode($cognome) . '&squadra=' . urlencode($squadra));
```

this is the code minimized to see you delete all the errors:

```
    $user = $_POST['user'];
$psw = $_POST['psw'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$recapito = $_POST['recapito'];
$email = $_POST['cognomenome'];
$sq = $_POST['squadra'];
$fanta = "ecce";

echo $user, $psw, $email, $recapito, $email, $sq, $fanta;

$res = get_data('http://www.campionandoalivorno.it/iwebkit/set_register.asp?' . 'user=' . urlencode($user) . '&pwd=' . urlencode($pwd) . '&email=' . urlencode($email) . '&recapito=' . urlencode($recapito)  . '&fanta=' . urlencode($fanta) . '&cognome=' . urlencode($cognome) . '&squadra=' . urlencode($squadra));
```

if I pass the link directly from the browser with strings of text works grrrrr, i can not understand.
A great thank you to who can help me

Comment: What is get_data? There is no PHP function like this. 
http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=get_data&scope=quickref
You can use file_get_contents() instead.

Comment: $cognome and $squadra do not exist, but you are trying to add them to the URL.

Comment: Sure it's not a $_POST Vs. $_GET issue?

Answer (score 0):

`$cognome` and `$squadra` do not exist, but you are trying to add them to the URL. Notice that you have `$sq` but not used it in the URL, and you have attempted to set `$email` twice. How about `psw`? Do you mean `pwd`? So you probably mean to do this:

```
$user     = $_POST['user'];
$pwd      = $_POST['psw'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$recapito = $_POST['recapito'];
$cognome  = $_POST['cognomenome'];
$sq       = $_POST['squadra'];
$fanta    = "ecce";


$res = get_data('http://www.campionandoalivorno.it/iwebkit/set_register.asp?' . 'user=' . urlencode($user) . '&pwd=' . urlencode($pwd) . '&email=' . urlencode($email) . '&recapito=' . urlencode($recapito)  . '&fanta=' . urlencode($fanta) . '&cognome=' . urlencode($cognome) . '&squadra=' . urlencode($sq));
```

For better experience, maybe try this:

```
<?php

$query_string = http_build_query(array(
    'fanta'    => "ecce",
    'user'     => (isset($_POST['user'])        ? $_POST['user']        : ''),
    'pwd'      => (isset($_POST['psw'])         ? $_POST['psw']         : ''),
    'email'    => (isset($_POST['email'])       ? $_POST['email']       : ''),
    'recapito' => (isset($_POST['recapito'])    ? $_POST['recapito']    : ''),
    'cognome'  => (isset($_POST['cognomenome']) ? $_POST['cognomenome'] : ''),
    'squandra' => (isset($_POST['squadra'])     ? $_POST['squandra']    : '')
));

$res = get_data('http://www.campionandoalivorno.it/iwebkit/set_register.asp?' . $query_string);
```